# Does this sum converge? Does it converge absolutely? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-\sqrt{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Does this sum converge? Does it converge absolutely?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-\sqrt{n-1}}$$

I first checked absolute convergence. Taking the absolute value of the term, we get $\frac{1}{n-\sqrt{n-1}}$

We know $n-\sqrt{n-1} < n \implies \frac{1}{n - \sqrt{n-1}} > \frac{1}{n}$

We know the harmonic series diverges, so our series will also diverge. So it does not converge absolutely.

But for the convergence, I’m stuck. Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ gives $1$, so the the series can either converge or diverge, so it doesn’t seem to help. What else should I do?

Comment: Apply Alternating Series Test.

Comment: @geetha290krm For that, I would need to show that $a_n$ is decreasing, how do I do that if $a_{n+1}\over a_n $ gives $1$ for $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: It is decreasing.

Comment: You need to show that $\frac{1}{n+1-\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{n-\sqrt{n-1}}$, which is a straightforward calculation.

Comment: @MartinR If we invert the fraction, we get $n+1 - \sqrt{n} > n - \sqrt{n-1} \implies 1 + \sqrt{n-1} > \sqrt{n}$, how is that straightforward ?

Comment: @wengen: Square both sides of that inequality ...

Comment: @MartinR $1 + 2\sqrt{n-1} + n -1 > n \implies 2\sqrt{n-1} > 0$ Uh yes in fact, seen like that it makes sense. Thank you very much !

Comment: @wengen: Note that the ratio test (and the root test), if applicable, proves *absolute* convergence of a series. So those tests *cannot* help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Per the Alternating Series Test, you need only show that

1. $a_n \to 0$, and
2. $|a_n|$ is (eventually) a decreasing function of $n$.

For (1) compare $\{a_n\}$ with the sequence $\{\frac{2}{n}\}$.

For (2) notice that $|a_n| = f(n)$, where
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x - \sqrt{x - 1}} ,$$ and show that that $f'(x) < 0$ on, e.g., $[2, \infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

$a_n = \frac{1}{n - \sqrt{n-1}}$ is positive and converges to zero. If we can show that $(a_n)$ is decreasing then $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converges by the alternating series test:
$$
\begin{align}
 a_{n+1} \le a_n &\iff n+1-\sqrt n \ge n - \sqrt{n-1} \\
 &\iff 1 \le \sqrt{n}-\sqrt {n-1} \\
 &\iff \sqrt{n}+\sqrt {n-1} \le 1 \, ,
\end{align}
$$
which is true. (The last step is a multiplication with $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt {n-1} > 0$).